# Center position image over a div

Tags: css, html, positioning

```
<img src="logo.jpg">
<div class="fadehover">
    <div class="a" ><img src="kulte_gray.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="b" ><img src="kulte.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Actually I want to center the image exactly above the div container. Ok i tried with a simple `<center>` tag it works but im not sure if this is the smart solution for all browsers. Any ideas? smthing like align it over the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    #logo {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

↑ This will center the `#logo` within its parent container.

```
<div class="fadehover">
    <img src="logo.jpg" id="logo">
    <div class="a" ><img src="kulte_gray.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="b" ><img src="kulte.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

**OR:**

```
<!-- If you cannot put #logo into .fadehover
     for some reason -->
<div id="same-width-as-fadehover">
    <img src="logo.jpg" id="logo">
</div>
<div class="fadehover">
    <div class="a" ><img src="kulte_gray.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="b" ><img src="kulte.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```